# REST and "never delete anything" applications

Tags: rest, architecture

In all enterprise applications I've seen pretty much nothing gets actually deleted from persistent storage, it's just marked as deleted with a flag or delete date. If I'm designing such an application should I ever use `DELETE` requests? If they should be used, how exactly they should look like? For example, if I want to let's say block a credit card I would issue something like

```
POST /block_orders
card_number=123&reason=card_stolen
```

But the app doesn't look RESTful if it doesn't use all of the available verbs. Does `DELETE` has any place in enterprise?

UPD: Is it good design to allow to `DELETE` a resource if you can `GET` that resource later to view history of operations, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a PATCH / PUT to me:

If you want to change the state of the credit card (to blocked) use PATCH [more info here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789).

```
PATCH /users/<user_id>/credit_cards/<creditcard_id>/
JSON 
{
  "reason": "stolen"
}
```

If you are giving all the resource with the request, to edit it knowing its identifier, use PUT.

DELETE fits perfectly with the deleted flag approach. Just update that flag when you receive DELETE request and if the user tries to retrieve the resource, just give her/him the available info for that blocked credit card. But in your scenario I would not use it to block credit cards... I would use it when a user wants to cancel that credit card, and also I would use soft deletion (delete flag) because maybe you are interested in statistical process or something... corporations have reasons not to delete data... :)

Comment: So, since pretty much any resource can be accessed later (at least by admins) then `DELETE` is almost never an appropriate verb to use, right?

Comment: It depends on your business logic: I would try the PATCH approach to change its state to blocked and depending on that credit card's state I would retrieve credit card's info when requested. If you use delete and after that, you try to GET the resource... it is kinda "ugly" for me...

Comment: You can't use PATCH with just plain `application/json`.  That media type has no patching semantics.  As rfc5789 explains you need to use a media type that describes how the target resource needs to be patched.  That's what 'application/json-patch+json' is for. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902 And using patching for something as simple as changing a state is overkill IMHO.

Comment: I think you are talking about JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Patch (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) and my link is about PATCH Method for HTTP (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789), HTTP method as it was mentioned in the question. RFC 5789 does not stand for a content-type. As I can read in (http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json-patch+json), application/json-patch+json is for "Applications that use this media type: Applications that manipulate JSON documents" but you do not necessary modify a JSON document...

Answer (score 2):

DELETE has a place in the enterprise.

Use DELETE requests to flag records as deleted, and hide those records from GET requests: as far as the client is concerned, those records *are* deleted.

Don't worry that those records can be recovered; even if you deleted them from the database, they could still be recovered from the backups. Nothing is *really* deleted nowadays. :-)

Comment: Thing is they aren't deleted and clients still can `GET` them to view history, for example.

Comment: I would treat the history as a different resource, then `GET` the history. Following this, it would not make sense to issue a `DELETE` to an entities history.

Comment: @synapse: If your clients can still GET deleted records, you're Doing It Wrong (TM). Better to _not_ return deleted records, and to allow privileged (e.g. 'admin') users the option of specifying whether or not they want to GET deleted records. I typically use an 'is_deleted' parameter, with possible values of yes|no|all. My apps then ignore that parameter (or force it to 'no') for non-privileged users.

Answer (score 1):

The DELETE HTTP method conveys the intent of the client to DELETE a resource.  There is no requirement on the server to actually physically delete it.  Feel free to just flag it.

And REST doesn't care if you don't use all the methods.  It only cares if you use one incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, obviously the resource is something more complex than a simple row in a database. But is it the proper design to allow someone to delete a resource if he can view it's history?

Comment: @synapse  You could do `DELETE /orders/234` and `GET /historical/orders/234`, now you did delete the first resource, you just happened to create a new one for viewing purposes.